# Loading datas with jquery with button into subscript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

when I open the website, the timestamp list will be loaded with Ajax. When I click onto the button < stop >, the script timestamp/stop will be executed, and the list will be reloaded after it with Ajax.

But, when I want to click second time into this list onto another stop button, nothing happens.

When I reload the whole site, I can delete one row again.
When I click after deleting a row onto the icon fa-refresh, there is a possibility to delete one row too.

But how can I solve this problem?

Main script:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "timestamp/list-open-all",
        data: "nachladen",
        success: function(nachladen){
            $('#nachladen').empty();
            $('<span>'+nachladen+'</span>').appendTo('#nachladen');
        }
    });

    $("#refresh-link-active-timestamps").click(function () {
        console.log('Daten gespeichert');
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "timestamp/list-open-all",
            data: "nachladen",
            success: function(nachladen){
                $('#nachladen').empty();
                $('<span>'+nachladen+'</span>').appendTo('#nachladen');
            }
        });
    });

    $("#button-timestamp-stop").click(function () {
        console.log('Button Stop in aktivem Zeitstempel gedrückt');
        var projectid = $("#button-timestamp-stop").attr('data-ts');
        console.log(projectid);
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'timestamp/stop/project/'+projectid,
            data: 'testdata=1', //pass data1 to second request
            success:  function(data){
                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "timestamp/list-open-all",
                    data: "nachladen",
                    success: function(nachladen){
                        $('#nachladen').empty();
                        $('<span>'+nachladen+'</span>').appendTo('#nachladen');
                    }
                });
            }    
      });   
    });
 });
 </script>
```

timestamp/list-open-all

```
<?php foreach($this->timestamps as $key => $value) { ?>
<div class="feed-element">
    <a href="profile.html" class="pull-left">
        <img alt="image" class="img-circle" src="img/profile/user/<?php echo $value['created_user'] ?>.jpg">
    </a>
    <div class="media-body ">
        <div class="actions">
            <a class="btn btn-xs btn-white" id="button-timestamp-stop" data-ts="<?php echo $value['id'] ?>"> stop </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: And here is the html part of the main script:

    <div class="ibox">
      <a class="refresh-link-active-timestamps" id="refresh-link-active-timestamps">
          <i class="fa fa-refresh"></i>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="ibox-content">
        <div id="nachladen">
           <div class="spinner spinner-bounce">
               <div class="bounce"></div>
           </div>
         </div>
     </div>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find it:

```
$(document).on("click", '#refresh-link-active-timestamps', function() {
```

instead of

```
$("#button-timestamp-stop").click(function () {
```